# Assign year to months of past 6 months

Tags: sql, oracle

From below data, how do i assign year in column DS_YEAR where Year is not assigned based on DS_MONTH.

```
DS_MONTH|   DS_DAY| DS_YEAR
--------|---------|--------
Mar     |   2     | 2019
Jan     |   4     | 2020
Apr     |   2     | 07:43
Sep     |   1     | 06:00
Jul     |   2     | 05:00
Dec     |   4     | 2019
Feb     |   7     | 2020
Nov     |   9     | 2019
```

From the above data; any data that is between now and past 6 months has a TIME instead of YEAR. However i want to write a query to attach the respective year instead of time.

I have below query which will attach the current year, however in case our data will lie in the months transitioning previous year it wont be accurate.

```
SELECT
    DS_MONTH || '-' || DS_DAY || '-' ||
    CASE
        WHEN DS_YEAR LIKE '%:%' THEN TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY')
        ELSE DS_YEAR
    END dsf
FROM
    MY_TABLE
```

How do i check the month whether it lies in current year or previous year, so that i can assign the correct year?

> Example: if today was FEBRUARY. and in my data i have `Sep        |   1     | 06:00` then my query should return `Sep-1-2019`
> and if today was OCTOBER it should return `Sep-1-2020`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
WITH sampledata (mon, d, yt) AS
(
SELECT 'Mar','2','2019' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 'Jan','4','2020' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 'Apr','2','07:43' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 'Sep','1','06:00' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 'Jul','2','05:00' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 'Dec','4','2019' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 'Feb','7','2020' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 'Nov','9','2019' FROM DUAL
),rundate (dt) AS
(
SELECT DATE'2021-05-30' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT s.mon, s.d, s.yt, 
       CASE WHEN TO_DATE(s.mon||'-'||s.d||'-'|| extract(year from r.dt),'Mon-dd-YYYY') > r.dt THEN TO_DATE(s.mon||'-'||s.d||'-'|| extract(year from ADD_MONTHS(r.dt,-12)),'Mon-dd-YYYY')
            ELSE TO_DATE(s.mon||'-'||s.d||'-'|| extract(year from r.dt),'Mon-dd-YYYY')
       END
  FROM sampledata s CROSS JOIN rundate r
 WHERE INSTR(s.yt,':') > 0
UNION
SELECT s.mon, s.d, s.yt, TO_DATE(s.mon||'-'||s.d||'-'|| s.yt,'Mon-dd-YYYY') 
  FROM sampledata s
 WHERE INSTR(s.yt,':') = 0;
```

UPDATE: Added the 'rundate' CTE so you can test with any date, not just sysdate. Also added the case expression to check ensure the date is in the past.

Comment: Koen Lostrie,The query still not okay, it assigns 2020 to those that don't need changing.  there may be need to add more condition

Comment: `SELECT TO_DATE(mon||'-'||d||'-'|| to_char(add_months( sysdate, -12 ),'yyyy'), 'Mon-dd-YYYY')
  FROM sampledata
 WHERE yt LIKE '%:%' AND upper(mon) NOT IN (select to_char(date '2020-12-01' + numtoyminterval(level,'month'),'MON') as month
  from dual
  connect by level <= (select to_char(sysdate,'mm') from dual))`

Comment: `UNION all
SELECT TO_DATE(mon||'-'||d||'-'|| extract(year from sysdate),'Mon-dd-YYYY') 
  FROM sampledata
 WHERE  yt LIKE '%:%' AND upper(mon) IN (select to_char(date '2020-12-01' + numtoyminterval(level,'month'),'MON') as month
  from dual
  connect by level <= (select to_char(sysdate,'mm') from dual))
UNION all
 SELECT TO_DATE(mon||'-'||d||'-'||  yt,  'Mon-dd-YYYY')
  FROM sampledata
 WHERE yt NOT LIKE '%:%'`

Comment: Still not okay, its assigning `2021` in one of the records

Comment: Omari, can you be more precise about which of the records is wrong ? In my example the run date is May 30, 2021, so some entries should be in the 2021. You can change that date in the "rundate" CTE to SYSDATE if you want to run it for today.

Comment: Its okay now, i did not catch that

Answer (score 0):

This is just pseudo code, may require few changes in date/month conversion as per db syntax

```
SELECT
    DS_MONTH || '-' || DS_DAY || '-' ||
    CASE
        WHEN DS_YEAR LIKE '%:%' and Month(sysdate)>6 THEN TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY')
        WHEN DS_YEAR LIKE '%:%' and Month(cast(DS_MONTH+'1 2015' as datetime)) < 6 THEN TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY')
        WHEN DS_YEAR LIKE '%:%' and Month(cast(DS_MONTH+'1 2015' as datetime)) > 6 THEN TO_CHAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()), 'YYYY')
        ELSE DS_YEAR
    END dsf
FROM
    MY_TABLE
```

Comment: Nice thought however the params don't do in my Oracle db.  but i get the idea